# working with Yii, is there any way to add AS to query via CDbCriteria

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii, fullcalendar

so there's the deal:

I've got a table set up for basic event management. This is done with all of the supporting code in place. I've decided to use the jquery calendar, Full Calendar for display via a JSON feed. This too is in place, but here's the hitch.

The data returned by CActiveRecord uses the keys as they are in the database, for example event_id, event_title, etc. When I output the data via Yii's CJSON::encode(), Full Calendar needs keys such as id, title, etc. I'd rather not change the database or my CRUD forms just to accommodate this calendar.

If I were writing my sql, I would just use AS (i.e., SELECT event_id AS id) to facilitate this change, however I can't see a way to do that in Yii. Any suggestions? Is there a way to add AS statements to the query in Yii?

Thanks all

Comment: I'm still curious to know if there is a way to the AS for field names in the query. I'm working with the relational view and am using afterFind() to work with the data. That said, I realized an easy solution that doesn't answer the question but solves my issue. A php str_replace on the JSON data for create the correct keys is all I neeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set alias in `select` clause:

```
$criteria->select = array(
    'id as user_id',
);
```